# Change flash player audio output device

Tags: audio, flash, hardware, out

Is there a way to change flash players audio output device? if not, is there a swf player who has this possibility? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an issue until a few minutes ago regarding this.

Two audio devices are available to my XP box: an iMic USB audio I/O device, in which I have permanently plugged my desktop speakers; and a pair of USB headphones with microphone that I plug in occasionally.

The USB headset would take precedence over the USB iMic for applications because apps appear to access the last device plugged in to a USB port. With this in mind, here was my issue:

- I would be listening to some Internettings on my USB headset.
- Later, I would want to use my desktop speakers for the Internettings.

This entailed unplugging my headset, shutting down Firefox and opening it up again. Because the desktop speakers are considered the most recently plugged in device, they would be default for plugins.

This is damned annoying, I said to myself, and decided a little hacker mode was in order.

Keeping Firefox open, I used Task Manager to kill the "plugin-container.exe" process. This showed a crash screen on any Flash Player applet in Firefox. Then I unplug the headset, and reload the Web page with the applet. Without restarting Firefox, Flash will then play through my desktop speakers.

If I wish to listen on the headset again, I plug the headset in, kill plugin-container.exe, and reload the page. Wham.

For as rare as I intend to switch audio devices, this will cover up part of the mess Adobe left.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that setting the audio device used by the flash player is something you would need to do on an OS level. You can change the device that flash uses for microphone and video input from the player's settings, but I don't think you can change audio output.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, at least for the Firefox browser, to direct HTML5 audio to a specific audio device:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chaudev/

Note: this is a new Firefox addon waiting to be reviewed developed by a friend of mine.

I have been waiting for this for years.

I wanted to use this when my wife is seeing YouTube on her Chrome browser and me seeing anything like Coursera online MOOC lectures (FF) on the TV which is connected to the pc. I wanted to hear my classes on the headset and my wife on the speakers for YouTube.

I have 2 mouses (one for me, wireless) and have installed a neat program called TeamPlayer which gives multiple cursors (each cursor for each mouse).

So I have now literally the capability of 2 persons working on 1 pc.

And on top of that it works seamlessly with "Enounce Myspeed" for speeding up the video lectures' playback.