# Dual audio output from browser?

Tags: flash, audio

I'm assuming this is flatly impossible, but has anyone ever heard of or seen a way to implement dual-audio output from within a browser, a la DJ software (user's hardware allowing)? Anything in Flash? Google searches don't seem to be giving me any love on this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://v3ga.net/YouTubeMixer/

Hours of fun.

Edit:

more links you may or may not have seen:

- [Change flash player audio output device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277062/change-flash-player-audio-output-device)
- http://www.justskins.com/forums/select-audio-device-to-101246.html
- http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/oUpyKYxjLGo

The consensus seems to be that flash (like most programs) has no control over the audio output device and will use the Windows default.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your question, I have revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Pretty much as I expected, then. I'll have a read of those links you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible at the moment, but you may eventually be able to do it using the Web Audio API, once that gets standardized and more widely implemented.

More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webaudio-20120315/#AudioDestinationNode

... and here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-audio/2012JanMar/0534.html